# RegEx exclude matches between quotes

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to exclude matches within quotes in RegEx. This String is my subject:

```
ONEKEY=VAL1, TWOKEY=VAL2, THREEKEY="VAL3.1, VAL3.2", FOURKEY=VAL4
```

I want to split this string (using `NSRegularExpression` in Mac OS) and get an associative array. To make it easier I first wanted to split the string into `KEY=VALUE` pairs and either easily explode them by `=` or use another RegEx in my iteration. My problem now is that I can't get exclusion of the quoted values work. Here is my RegEx:

```
(?=(.))([^,\s]*)
```

I already tried something like this: `(?=(.))([^"])?([^,\s]*)([^"])?` and `(?=([^"]?.[^"]?))([^,\s]*)`

Comment: I mean I'm "splitting". Of cause I'm **actually** using matching. But in the iteration of my matches I'm creating "splits" of my string. You'r right, it's not well couched :-)

Comment: I mean matching the key value pairs, instead of trying to split them. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about finding:

```
([^=]+)=("[^"]*"|[^,]+)(?:,\s*)?
```

Then extract group 1 (the key) and 2 (the value(s)).

`[^=]+` - one or more characters that aren't `=`.
`"[^"]*"` - any characters between quotes.
`[^,]+` - one or more characters that aren't `,`.
`(?:,\s*)?` - consume the `,` with any spaces after it (the only difference between `(...)` and `(?:...)` is that the latter doesn't assign a group to it).

This won't work if brackets can be nested.

[Test](http://www.rubular.com/r/jixeHKB3eA).

Comment: Note that this doesn't validate the input string. If there is an error in the input string, this method will fail to detect and just match anything that satisfy the regex.

Comment: @nhahtdh Indeed. I just made the bare minimum required assumptions about the input. Assuming this would be a valid change, changing `[^=]` to `[^=,"\s]` (or possibly `\w`) and `[^,]` to `[^,"\s]`, along with checking starting and ending positions of the matches (`\G`?), might help to this end.

Comment: Actually, the more important thing is that the OP doesn't have a spec for the key value pair. Otherwise, writing a regex to match + validate would be very easy. (And yes, `\G` is very useful in parsing stuff like this).